# How To update rails 4.0 to rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How should i update my existing app from `rails 4.0` to `rails 4.1` . i know i have to update the gem . Is there also any other configuration to modify in the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, no one here knows the ins and outs of your application as you do. The best bet is to follow the [upgrade guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) and hopefully there are tests in place.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I'm doing it:

1. See that you have a sufficient test suite and that all tests pass
2. Review your Gemfile. What needs to be updated to be Rails 4.1 compatible?
   Update them now; see that your test suite still passes
3. Use railsdiff.org to see the basic changes to a new rails app and apply them accordingly
   http://railsdiff.org/diff/v4.0.3/v4.1.8/
4. Follow the official Rails guide for upgrading to Rails 4.1
   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html
5. Google for more guides on upgrading to Rails 4.1
   https://www.google.com/search?q=upgrade+to+rails+4.1
   They mention some more things you have to take care of when upgrading to Rails 4.1.
   Especially mentioning some non-default gems, like Rspec etc.
6. Run your test suite, see that all tests pass. Update or fix your code if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Ruby on Rails guide for upgrading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html). It depends on how your app is built already.